# Write a filter Factory populated at import time in Python using metaclasses

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, factory, metaclass

I want a simple way to implement new filters in a module. They would eventually be automatically recognized by the library at import.

For example, if I want the list of all filters I do:

```
>>> FilterFactory.available_filters 
{
    'upper': __main__.FilterUpper,
    'lower': __main__.FilterLower,
    'trim': __main__.FilterTrim
}
```

My first approach was to use a `classmethod` and a LRU Cache:

```
class FilterFactory:
    @classmethod
    @lru_cache()
    def available_filters(cls):
        fmap = {}
        for _, member in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
            if not inspect.isclass(member) or not hasattr(member, 'name'):
                continue
            if member.name() == 'base':
                continue
            fmap[member.name()] = member
        return fmap
```

Then I realized that it is better to build the factory when the module is loaded using metaclasses:

```
from abc import abstractmethod


class FilterFactory:
    available_filters = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, filter_: type):
        # if not issubclass(filter_, Filter):
        #     raise InvalidFilterError(f'Invalid filter: {filter_}')
        cls.available_filters[filter_.name] = filter_
        setattr(cls, filter_.name, filter_)

    def __new__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs):
        if name not in cls.available_filters:
            raise ValueError(f'Unknown filter: {name}')
        return cls.available_filters[name](*args, **kwargs)


class MetaFilter(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        if not name.startswith('Filter') and name != 'BaseFilter':
            raise ValueError('Filter class names must start with "Filter"')
        new_class.name = name.split('Filter', maxsplit=1)[1].lower()
        if name != 'BaseFilter':
            FilterFactory.register(new_class)
        return new_class


class BaseFilter(metaclass=MetaFilter):
    """ Base class for filters. """
    @abstractmethod
    def filter(self, value: str) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError("Filter.filter() must be implemented")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}'

    def __call__(self, value: str) -> str:
        return self.filter(value)


class FilterUpper(BaseFilter):
    def filter(self, value: str) -> str:
        return value.upper()


class FilterRegex(BaseFilter):
    def __init__(self, pattern: str, replace: str):
        self.pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        self.replace = replace
        
    def filter(self, value: str) -> str:
        return self.pattern.sub(value, self.replace)
```

This looks neat, but it has some flaws:

1. I cannot ensure the filter passed to `register` is indeed a subclass of `BaseFilter` because this base class isn't yet declared. Unlike C++ I cannot do forward declarations in Python.
2. I must specifically prevent the abstract class `BaseFilter` to be added to the `available_filters`.
3. This pattern looks a bit odd.

The goal is to be able to use `FilterFactory.available_filters` to build a JSON schema validator that only accepts available filters. And use the factory to create then apply filters multiple times during the execution of the program. The validation may be done with `voluptuous` by adding some extra in the metaclass:

```
class MetaFilter(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        ...
        new_class.__params__, new_class.__types__ =
            cls.extract_parameters(new_class)
        return new_class
    
    @classmethod
    def extract_parameters(cls, new_class):
        """ Extract parameters from the class.
        Ensure that all the parameters are annotated."""
        params = dict(inspect.signature(new_class.__init__).parameters)
        for key in ['self', 'args', 'kwargs']:
            if key in params:
                del params[key]
        for param, value in params.items():
            if value.annotation is inspect.Parameter.empty:
                raise ValueError(
                    f'Filter {new_class.name} has an untyped parameter: {param}'
                )
    
        return (params.keys(), [p.annotation for p in params.values()])
```

Then I can create a validation schema with:

```
filters = {}
for filter_name, filter_class in FilterFactory.available_filters.items():
    filters[Optional(filter_name)] = All(
        ExactSequence(filter_class.__types__),
        lambda args: FilterFactory(filter_name, *args)
    )
schema = Schema({'filter': filters})

s = schema({
    'filter': {
        'regex': ['foo', 'bar']
    }
})

assert(s['filter']['regex'].filter('foo') == 'bar')
```

If the filter is missing from the implementation, the validation fails. Adding a new filter to the application is as simple as adding this filter in the `filters.py` module.

Is this implementation Zen and Pythonic? What better option can I use?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:
The idea is good - I don't see the problem of "can't forward reference classes" as a real one,a s a filter class will have to import `BaseFilter` anyway, even if it is in a different file, and therefore, it has to be made available early, or the program won't even run. (that is: you won't get a class declared as inheriting from BaseFilter that dos not, in fact, does so).

That said, since Python 3.6 there is a new feature in the language that does away with the need for a metaclass in this case (and as a bonus, it even simplifies the fact that `BaseFilter` itself is not  a filter): the `__init_subclass__` method.

It should be written as a plain method on a base-class - it will always be a class method, even without being decorated with `@classmethod`, and it will be called for each new subclass, with the subclass as first argument: you can write all your registering logic in that method. (ANd it is not called for the base class, where it should be declared, itself).

[init subclass documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__)